Why does the author assume \$R_{in} = 1/ g_m \$ for this this circuit?
The following circuit is from Chapter 13 of Analog Design Essentials, page 1324, written by Willy Sansen.
Calculate \$R_{in}\$ for this circuit.

The author thinks \$R_{in} = 1 / g_m\$
However,
$$
-V_T g_m  + \frac{V_{out} - V_T} {r_o} = - I_T
$$
$$
\frac{V_{out}} {R_L} =I_T
$$
$$
R_{in}
=
\frac{V_T} {I_T}
=
\left(\frac{R_L} {r_o} +1 \right) 
\left(\frac{1} {g_m} \middle |\middle|\, {r_o} \right) 
=
\frac{R_L + r_o} {g_m r_o + 1}
\approx
\frac{R_L + r_o} {g_m r_o}
$$

For large values of ro the final expression reduces to 1/gm.

@KevinWhite Where am I wrong in my calculation? Do you $r_o \gg R_L$?

This could be true if RL is much smaller than ro. If the load RL is an ideal current source you cannot make that approximation.

@internet Why do you think $R_L$ is an ideal current source? I think it's just a resistor

@kile I was giving a general case.

@internet If $R_L$ is current source, it should be removed in small signal analysis.

@kile no, that isn't the case in most current sources with transistors, you still have ro as output impedance of the current source.

@kile - yes, ro would be expected to much larger than RL. If it is a current source with an equivalent resistance not much lower than ro then it would not apply - the diagram shows a resistor.

@kile - Do you realize that here you have calculated the input resistance at the source node as (1/gm) assuming ro>>RL ? This is correct but it is in contrast to other calculations you have presented while assuming that the voltage division expression  would be VX/VT=R1/(R1+R2). Two different results for the same task description?
